# Jenkins pipeline & mongoose database connection during unit tests: ECONNREFUSED

Tags: mongodb, docker, jenkins, mongoose, jenkins-pipeline

I'v been having problems connecting the mongoDB in the Jenkinsfile test stage. The base image is mongo -image from dockerhub.

My unit test first tries to connect to mongoDB with:

```
mongoose.connect(mongodb://localhost:27017/datastore_test, options);
```

but fails with:

> MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on
>   first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED
>   127.0.0.1:27017]

I also tried with `'mongodb://mongo:27017/datastore_test'` but no success.

Is there some tricks or caveats how to connect to database during the CI pipeline with docker?

Here is how my Jenkinsfile looks like:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'myusername/mongonode:latest'
            args '-p 3000:3000'
        }
    }
    environment {
        CI = 'true'
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'npm install'
            }
        }
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh 'npm test'
            }
        }
        stage('Deliver') {
            steps {
                sh './jenkins/scripts/deliver.sh'
                input message: 'Finished using the web site? (Click "Proceed" to continue)'
                sh './jenkins/scripts/kill.sh'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: Output of `docker inspect 8ad397858ecd | grep IP`

```
docker inspect 8ad397858ecd | grep IP
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
```

Comment: can you put the output of `docker inspect mongo-container-name | grep IP` here?

Comment: I added it with edit

Comment: so, now you can try to connect MongoDB on IP `172.17.0.2` and definitely it shouldn't be `localhost`.

Comment: for using mongodb with host name you should specefiy it in docker run command or docker compose.

Comment: Ah okay thanks. I shall test

Comment: The connection with IP did not work and neither did specifying the mongoDB port and volume in run command. Said in test job, that port 27017 is already reserved.